# Pycharm unable to install packages in pycharm - Non-zero exit code (1) -

Tags: python, pycharm

I cannot install packages in PyCharm. (Pandas, DateTime)
I tried to install them in the command line as well but it does not work either.I have only one version of Python installed 3.7 and this is used in the project interpreter

Please help.

Below my error message:

"Collecting pandas
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pandas/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available."

Comment: your python binary wasn't compiled with the _ssl module.  what happens if you do a ```python -c 'import ssl'```?

Comment: I tried it in the command line. I get an error: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Ok, the error is solved and I managed to run the command you suggested but nothing happens unfortunately

Comment: Follow my solution and let me know the result. Thanks